# MSdeploy error while deploying to Azure with set parameters

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, teamcity

I am using Msdeploy in teamcity to deploy asp.net application to Azure cloud.I like to use setparameters.xml so that i can deploy different config entries for different sites.

When i tried following command and parameters  it did't throw any error messages but not getting desired results ( config entries where not modified in web.config)

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
```

```
-verb:sync -source:contentPath="%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\MySite" 
 -dest:contentPath='%azureSite%',ComputerName="https://%azurePublishUrl%/msdeploy.axd?site=%azureSite%",UserName='%azureUsername%',Password='%azurePassword%',AuthType='Basic'

-setParamFile:"%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\MySite.SetParameters.xml"
```

I tried to modify above parameter statement like below

```
-source:package='%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\MySite.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://%azurePublishUrl%/msdeploy.axd?site=%azureSite%",userName="%azureUsername%",password="%azurePassword%",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\MySite.SetParameters.xml"
```

and got following error message.

> in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\24caecb58f06574f
>
> [18:30:53][Step 2/2] Info: Using ID 'd7980b43-c13e-4b7a-95c1-1da8c5acdc6b' for connections to the remote server.
>
> [18:30:55][Step 2/2] Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
>
> [18:30:55][Step 2/2] Info: Creating application (https://MySite-dev.azurewebsites.net/)
>
> [18:30:55][Step 2/2] Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP
>
> [18:30:55][Step 2/2] More Information: Could not complete an operation with the specified provider ("createApp") when connecting using the Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user for this operation. createApp http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP.

Is it a valid error? what is the difference between these two parameters how can i apply setParameter.xml values copied in to web.config for different sites?

I took site details (user name , password , site url ) from Azure publish details option in azure portal.

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes

Comment: How about this ??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997844/dotnet-publish-going-wrong-unable-to-find-create-approot-folder/38020591#38020591

Answer (score 1):

Parameterization is only supported for the `package` and `archiveDir` providers per [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084(v=ws.10).aspx).

I believe the error you provided for the second MSDeploy call indicates the creds you are using to deploy with do not have access to create an IIS web application on the target server.  You should test creating the site manually and then deploying again to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks cheif7 you are right , Parameterization is only supported for the package and archiveDir

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it was helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks cheif7 , it is not solving the problem , still not sure how to set parameters for azure deployment .

Comment: Did you try creating the site manually and then deploying? As mentioned in the answer it looks like the error is due to the user not having permission to create the site.

Comment: Thanks Cheif7 , managed to deploy package throuh azure powershell command Publish-AzureWebSiteProject.